# How to get Request JSON Message with in the Exception Handler - WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I created webApi global exception handler, i have to log the request parameters/JSON in the prod environment to verify the request if any exception happened, Please let me know the way to log the request message with in the

```
ExceptionHandler
```

.

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), 
            new GlobalExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

**GlobalExceptionHandler**

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
     Logger.log("Exception : \t" + context.Exception.Message)
         Logger.log("Request JSON : \t" + Josn.Serializer(context.Request.Content));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the above code?

Comment: Not able to get the Request JSON from body of the WebAPI request, here i am not able get that request

Comment: Have you check the context.RequestContext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reading the content like following.

For `POST/PUT/DELETE` following code will read the content.

```
     string jsonContent = "";
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
         {    
          jsonContent= reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
         }

 //Reset back the position
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

For `GET` request you can log the `URL` directly.

Comment: not able to access httpContext with in the ExceptionHandler.. Let me know how to access

Comment: I have updated the answer, you should be able to get it like System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream

Comment: Did you got the content?

Comment: Thanks i am able to access the HttpContext, but reader.TeadToEnd().ToString() is retruns empty string even though content length is 27. Please let me know what i did wrong

Comment: Did you checked what content is getting posted through developer console or fiddler?

Comment: it workd after I moved System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0; beginning of the code.

Comment: Why use `.ToString()` on string, which you got from `.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @DominikSzymański , you are right, ToString is not required here. I’ll update